# Symfony app.php refresh cache

Tags: php, symfony, caching

First version of Controller had this one Route:

```
/**
 * @Route("/troll", name="route_troll")
 */
public function trollAction() {...}
```

I made `php app/console cache:clear` and `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`
. Then I went to urls: `app.php/troll` and `app_dev.php/troll`. Both work very well.

Then I changed Controller to this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/trolls", name="route_troll")
 */
public function trollsAction() {...}
```

I wrote console comands once again, and then I tried to test urls...

On app_dev.php:

`/troll - error 404 - ok`

`/trolls - rendered template - ok`

On app.php:

`/troll - rendered template - wtf?`

`/trolls - error 404 - wtf?`

I tried even force delete all `./app/cache/*` files by file manager, but it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer. Just delete var/cache/prod/* and then run php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug